# Auto deploy the jar file as tomcat does

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8, jasperserver

Tomcat has an option to automatically detect and deploy code changes without the server requiring a restart.  Spend some time looking into how this works and what we need to do to use this feature for Jasper server-pro.

Comment: are you using spring boot maven project? If yes, then you need to add one dependency called "spring-boot-devtool". It will automatically detects any changes in file & restarts the applications automatically.

Comment: No it's not a spring boot project rather it's a traditional spring framework.